# This system does not support OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I just got the error this system does not support openGL while opening stellarium. I've search the internet to finds a solution but couldn't find anything that works... I have ubuntu 12.04 and the Nvdia GT 540m video card

Answer (score 1):

1st: Open Terminal and run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`

2nd: Then run: `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` (to remove any unneeded nvidia packages that could interfere with the setup)

3rd: After that in the terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

4th: After it downloads the latest drivers and installs them, go to your Update Manager, refresh updates and get any Ubuntu-X team updates(then run `sudo nvidia-xconfig`), then restart.
If followed correctly your NVIDIA drivers should work perfectly.